# Does Jest have a way to conditionally return a value based on input?

Tags: jestjs

I'm used to do mocking (actually, faking, but, whatever) with Sinon.js by using `withArgs` extensively to conditionally return the fake value. And now I'm trying to migrate to Jest and I'm can't find anything similar in the mock API.

What I want:

```
const t = sinon.stub();
t.withArgs('foo').returns('bar'); 

console.log(t('foo')); // 'bar'
console.log(t('qux')); // undefined
```

It seems that the only way to do that in Jest is by using `mockImplementation`, which means that I must write the arg matcher by hand.

Is there a better way of doing this in Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, there isn't any Jest builtin method.

There is an issue opened [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6779) and a feature proposal [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6180).

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697513/can-i-mock-functions-with-specific-arguments-using-jest), there is a third party library that does something similar: https://github.com/timkindberg/jest-when