# Mocking axios requests on specific urls with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I'd like to know if it's possible to mock axios requests with different values depending on url. I use jest and typescript. Now I have this working example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest';
jest.mock('axios');
    
const mAxios = mocked(axios, true);
mAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'john doe',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'keyboard cat',
    },
  ],
});
```

It works but as you can see it always returns the same value no matter to where request was send. I'm wondering how can I achieve my goal.

Comment: Provide a `mockImplementation`? But I wouldn't recommend mocking Axios, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107497/3001761 for options.

Comment: Otherwise it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41697513/3001761.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.mockImplementation()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) callback:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest';
jest.mock('axios');

const mAxios = mocked(axios, true);
mAxios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
    switch (url) {
        case '/users.json':
            return Promise.resolve({data: [{id: 1, title: 'john doe'}]})
        case '/items.json':
            return Promise.resolve({data: [{id: 1, item: 'whatever'}]})
        default:
            return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'))
    })
}
```